# Single Token Field in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to create a field in Elasticsearch from my java code.

It's getting tokenized and therefore sorting and searching are not working as expected.

I'm trying to use this analyzer but it's not working

```
[
  {
    "name": "email",
    "type": "string",
    "filters": [
      "lowercase",
      "shingle"
    ],
    "tokenizers": [
      "uax_url_email"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please show your whole mapping and index settings, as it's not clear what the above snippet is for. It looks like an analyzer definition, but not 100% sure. The more info your provide, the more chances you have of getting an answer.